# Providing Options like Callback in get() in Couchbase PHP Client

Tags: php, callback, couchbase

I am using [PHP Client for couchbase](https://github.com/couchbase/php-couchbase)

```
    $cluster = new CouchbaseCluster(127.0.0.1); 
    $bucket = $cluster->openBucket('default');
    $doc = $uds->get(array('key1','key2'));
```

In this case the this $doc is of type CouchbaseMetaDoc class. However I need to process each $doc fetched using a callback function.

As per the old (1.2.0) [API documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-php-client-1.2.0/classes/Couchbase.html#method_get) it only support missing objects but it is passed as one of the $options as an array in the new [client version (2.1.0)](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.1.0/classes/CouchbaseBucket.html)

Comment: Your question is unclear can you define it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're looking for, but it seems to be the old callback that isn't there at all in the 2.x client.  I'm not sure what you're referring to in the last sentence.

The original 1.2 API mostly mirrored the pecl-memcached API.  The callback though was not really correct and building a pecl extension that would be correct isn't really possible because many things in scope would be lost by the time the callback was to be executed.  Since it wasn't correct and really shouldn't be done, it was dropped going in to 2.x.

If you want to process each document, that's best done in context of the request.  There might be a framework which can give you the asynchronous behavior you're looking for as well but PHP does not allow an extension to do that.

The `options` to many of the K-V methods [are documented](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.1.0/classes/CouchbaseBucket.html#method_upsert) per method and it's usually just expiry.

Comment: Ok, even I think the callback is removed in 2.x but the new API doc says get(string|array $ids, array $options = array()) : mixed. Any idea what are the options ?

Comment: In the last sentence I assumed the callback option is still there but as one of the options array argument http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.1.0/classes/CouchbaseBucket.html#method_get

Comment: I've updated the answer about the options and also asked to have it a bit more clear in the docs: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/PCBC-377

Comment: Thanks. Since the callback feature is no more I decided to loop through the result array after get. Thanks

Comment: If that'll meet your needs, I think that's best.  Please mark my answer as correct if it helped.  :)